# Modal dialog on javafx hangs unpredictably

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, modal-dialog, javafx

Class extending from `javafx.stage.Stage` using `Modality.Application_MODAL` causes the application (sometimes the operating system too) to hang for an unpredictable time.

I have a class

```
ModalDialog extends Stage{
    ModalDialog(){
        super(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    }
}
```

On calling showAndWait() of an instance of the above class the app hangs for an unpredictible time. This happends on Ubuntu Linux 13.10. 
The `jconsole` shows stacktrace of the `JavaFX-ApplicationThread` is:

```
com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.enterNestedEventLoopImpl(Native Method)
com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._enterNestedEventLoop(GtkApplication.java:144)
com.sun.glass.ui.Application.enterNestedEventLoop(Application.java:384)
com.sun.glass.ui.EventLoop.enter(EventLoop.java:83)
com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.enterNestedEventLoop(QuantumToolkit.java:523)
javafx.stage.Stage.showAndWait(Stage.java:398)
```

Is there a known explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: Is the [ConditionalFeature.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/ConditionalFeature.html#TRANSPARENT_WINDOW) supported on your machine?  Does any of the information in the javadoc for that feature help you diagnose your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Its best to set an intiOwner for the dialog for the system to know the parent frame of your dialog. This enables the dialog to be modal to the parent frame rather than just being modal to nothing. This can take care of your problem i think.

```
ModalDialog extends Stage{
     ModalDialog(Stage parentStage){
       super(StageStyle.Transparent);
       initOwner(parentStage);
       initModality(Modality.Application_Modal);
   }
```

This should do